# Forking in a loop does not work as thought

Tags: c, loops, fork

I want to have the main process to run and create 4 subprocesses. Once they are created I want the main process to wait for them to finish.

This is my whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


int main(){

    int i;
    int childID;
    int status;

    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        childID=fork();
        if (childID==0){
            printf("[%d] I the child, will sleep\n", (int)getpid());
            sleep(1);
        }
    }

    if (!childID){
        wait(&status);
        printf("[%d] I the parent, have waited for my children!\n", (int)getpid());
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What I get instead is this:

```
..
[8508] I the child, will sleep
[8503] I the parent, have waited for my children!
[8511] I the child, will sleep
[8510] I the child, will sleep
[8509] I the child, will sleep
[8520] I the child, will sleep
[8511] I the parent, have waited for my children!
[8510] I the parent, have waited for my children!
(prompt stuck)
```

Why does the parent print out multiple times instead of once, in the end?

Comment: Your output does not match your code. Correct it please

Comment: The code you gave us has no statement that prints "I the parent, will wait for my children!". Is there more to the code?

Comment: Besides the fact that your children will fork too, as mentioned in the answers, you are also only waiting for the last forked child, instead of all your children.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's just that I swapped the position of wait() and printf at last minute and forgot to update the output as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is not the parent who writes multiple times, but the first 3 children. When you `fork`, the children gets an exact copy of the process including its address space, stack, registers, everything. That means that after the first `fork` both the parent and the new child will go through the `for` 3 more times creating 3 new childs. You should `break` out of the `for` when executing as the children for the desired effect:

```
    if (childID==0){
        printf("[%d] I the child, will sleep\n", (int)getpid());
        sleep(1);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking that once fork() is run only the code after it will run. So as fork is inside the loop I was thinking that maybe it will bypass the whole loop and continue after it..

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pids of the prints. 8510 and 8511 are children, not the original parent. When you fork in the loop, the children are also in that loop. Try putting a `break;` after the sleep(1).

Answer (score 0):

When you run the loop, once you fork, the child sleeps during the first iteration after it is forked off, but then it forks off more processes. Since `childID` is no longer `0` for those processes, the do not call wait and so they do not reap their children. This means that when all of the wait calls are completed you will still have processes running, so the terminal will hang.